# sometimes when I use createApp(App).use(...)... everything disappear

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I was trying to use vuex in my vue project.When I directly use  the store everything is fine.But when I try to put the store in module then use it,everything just gone.

Also,if I import router from my router.js and use it ,everything will gone.

Super confused about it.

the way I directly use it

```js
import a from "./store/modudel/a"
```

the way I put in module

```js
// main.js
import store from "./store/index";

createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .mount("#app");
```

```js
// store/index.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import a from './module/a';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    a
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `store/index.js` contains code specific to Vue 2, but your `main.js` is for Vue 3. This code should be causing linter errors in the dev terminal or runtime errors in the browser console.

Assuming you have a Vue 3 project with Vuex 4, the equivalent store code would be:

```js
// store/index.js
import { createStore } from 'vuex';

import a from './module/a';

export default createStore({
  modules: {
    a
  }
});
```